# Selecting the most recent insert with db_select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, drupal

I have a question about a db_select query in drupal:

```
  db_insert('CON_CON')
    ->fields(array(
            'surname' => $form_state['values']['surname'],
            'firstname' => $form_state['values']['firstname'],

    ))->execute();
   $hasCONID = db_select('CON_CON', 'n')
        ->fields('n',array('CONID'))
        ->condition('surname', $form_state['values']['surname'], '=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchfield()



   db_insert('CASL_NEW')
        ->fields(array(
            'CONID' => $hasCONID,

    ))->execute();
```

This returns the CONID of a column, where the column surname matches the surname of the form. But there's a chance there will be duplicate surnames, so is a condition I can put in that returns the most recent insert made into the table? Or to select all rows that were made in a certain time? Or is there another way to make sure it selects the most recent surname instead of another duplicate?

Comment: Not sure how to do it in Drupal (you may need to create your own function to extend the Drupal function) but you can use the new PDO `return $db->lastInsertId('yourIdColumn');` at the end of your insert function to return the last ID... You can then use this as an argument for your search query

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`db_last_insert_id`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.pgsql.inc/function/db_last_insert_id/6)

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {table}(name) VALUES ('value')");
echo db_last_insert_id('table_name', 'name');
```

Comment: `db_last_insert_id()` was removed in Drupal 7, and this question refers only to Drupal 7. I can't imagine why this has been accepted, it's completely wrong.